# No match for operator>>

Tags: c++

it says there is a problem with this function. It should get input from the user for number of spools to be ordered and then output the input it recieved. (thinking of adding a confirmation dialog if there is time).

```
/********************************************/
// Name: inspools                            /
// Description: Ask for and get number of    /
// spools                                    /
// Parameters: N/A                           /
// Reture Value: spoolnum                    /
/********************************************/
int spoolnum()
{
  int spoolnum;

  cout << "Number of spools to be shipped: " << endl;
  cin >> spoolnum;
  cout >> spoolnum >> " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" >> endl;

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your arrows backwards in this line:

```
cout >> spoolnum >> " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" >> endl;
```

it should be:

```
cout << spoolnum << " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" << endl;
```

And your `return` statement needs to return something:

```
return spoolnum;
```

Comment: thanks that fixed that issue but now it says : " error: return statement with no value, in function returning int" even though i declared it. here is full code:

Comment: Yes, your `return` statement needs to return something. Try this `return 0;`

Comment: `return spoolnum;` might be better than `return 0;` if you want the code to match the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. you need to use `<<` with `cout`.

`ostream` has not operator overloaded for  `>>` and hence the error that you see.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << spoolnum << " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" << endl;
```

and your return statement should return spoolnum:

```
return spoolnum;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`cout >> spoolnum >> " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" >> endl;`

Should be:

`cout << spoolnum << " spool(s) of wire will be shipped" << endl;`